# ARM access to the Gremlin Endpoint in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Is it possible to get access to the Graph / Gremlin endpoint for a Cosmos database using ARM so it can, for example, be set as an app setting?

You can access the Document / SQL endpoint in ARM using syntax such as:

```
[reference('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/mydb').documentEndpoint]
```

However looking in resources.azure.com I can find no equivalent for the Gremlin endpoint and this is causing issues as there are now at least two endpoint formats for Graph / Gremlin databases in Azure:

```
mydb.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com (older format)
mydb.graphs.azure.com (newer format)
```

I've got a system deployed with mixed name formats across environments and am currently having to workaround it by passing in the distinct format of the name as a parameter however that's obviously a bit frail and requires me to have prior knowledge.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to get access to the Graph / Gremlin endpoint for a Cosmos database using ARM

Short answer is yes. Please havea try to do it with following code `reference(resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', 'gremlinAccount')).gremlinEndpoint` then we could get the

```
"gremlinEndpoint": "https://xxxx.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/",
```

The following is the demo code:

```
"variables": {
    "graphDbAccount": {
      "name": "gremlinAccount"
    },
    "resourceId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts', variables('graphDbAccount').name)]"
  }

"outputs": {
    "gremlinEndpoint": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(variables('resourceId')).gremlinEndpoint]"
    }
  }
```

[image]